# Check if a value exists in a file

Tags: python, file, process

I am trying to make a program that will allow me to choose a file or a process and search for a value in it. (And if it exists, I want it to return all of the addresses the value exist it)
For example, if i'll choose Chrome and search for my reputation value it should get me the address containing the reputation variable (plus all of the other addresses containing the same value).
Is there any way of doing such thing?
(An example for such a program is 'Cheat Engine' - This is exactly what I want to build)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your example, as it might involve some info from third parties (Google), but for checking if a value exists in a file you can easily load the file a use an if statement.

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'value' in line:
            do_whatever_you_want
```

Comment: I thought about this, but because I'm not sure how a file is saved (in what format) i don't know if it will be possible to do what I want this way.
Think of it this way, you choose a process, in which there is a value and a button which changes the value to a random one. What I want to do is to be able to find the address of the saved variable by the value. If something isn't clear, let me know.

Comment: @pystudent well, you really need to know what is the format of the file, otherwise, how of Earth would you know where to look for the value of that variable? Assuming a plain text file in which variables are stored line by line for example, you could find the variable and then print the whole line for instance. And then refine the output if you see you are able to do so using regex.

Comment: 'Cheat Engine' is a program that does exactly what I want, they are doing it pretty fast so i guess there is another solution / i haven't made myself clear.

Comment: @pystudent that's more complicated than just "check if a value exists in a file". It seems you are looking for a memory debugger instead, and if your plan is to build one, then I recommend you to start working on it and when you have a more detailed question, ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with an executable is extremely difficult. You're essentially asking to do a regex on everything in the address space of a given process and return the result of every match. There's no simple way to do this, but a regex will indeed be the best solution.

This process is much simpler in a text file. You merely have to open the file, search for your string, and return the results. Here's a recent project I've been working on that reads a saved SQL file, which is later searched for a pattern using `re`:

```
with open('filename.sql', 'r') as sqlfile:
    sql = sqlfile.read()
    if re.search('some pattern', sql):
        print('found it!')
```

Here's a link to Python's `re` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: 'Cheat Engine' is a program that does exactly what I want, they are doing it pretty fast so i guess there is another solution / i haven't made myself clear.